# H2 Database Primary Key Violation

Tags: sql, h2, composite-primary-key

I am trying to make inserts on a table with a Primary key composed of 2 attributes. However when I try to make an insert and one of the attributes in the primary key is identical to one already inserted I get the following error:

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_CCC ON PUBLIC.ABWESENHEIT(DATUM) VALUES
```

Here is my table:

```
Create TABLE Abwesenheit (

    s_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Schueler(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    entschuldigt BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    datum TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    kommentar VARCHAR(40),
    kalendereintrag_id VARCHAR(40) REFERENCES Schoolsubject(name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    PRIMARY KEY (s_id,datum)

);
```

And here are 2 inserts which reproduce the problem:

```
insert into Abwesenheit (s_id, entschuldigt, kommentar,datum,kalendereintrag_id) values (1,'false','','2015-12-21 11:59:00.0','Geschichte');
insert into Abwesenheit (s_id, entschuldigt, kommentar,datum,kalendereintrag_id) values (2,'false','','2015-12-21 11:59:00.0','Geschichte');
```

Even though the "datum" attribute defaults to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, I need to be able to insert custom timestamps (i.e. for retroactive entries)
.

Given the fact that the "s_id" is different in the two inserts they should work. However they do not. Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CONSTRAINT_INDEX_CCC suggests it may not be the primary key that is raising this error.  Do you have a 2nd unique index on your table?

Comment: Perhaps a constraint instead?  You can test if datum is limiting you to unqiue values by changing one of the date/times to 12:00:00.  I'm sure you've already checked this, but it is also worth double checking you don't have any existing records that conflict.

Comment: I did that and yes it lets me insert it. Datum appears to be the problem but I don't understand why it acts this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by another table which was referencing my table, under the assumption that the dates in the table Abwesenheit were unique.